# circuit isolation

Tags: power-supply

I have a project with LED strips using 5 volt. On the same power supply is a small audio amp running two 4 ohm speakers. The problem I’m having is the LED’s flash or blink with the base notes. I’m assuming I need power supply isolation. I tried using a RFM 0505 DC to DC converter to isolate the amp from the LED’s to no avail.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Schematic please.

Comment: Sounds more like your power supply is insufficient for the project, or your power distribution is poor, than an actual isolation problem.

Comment: Your 5V supply is overloaded. Running a DC-DC convertor off it may isolate the amp, but the excess demand is still there.

Comment: You have two speakers.  Remove 1 and see if you still have the problem.  If problem goes away, power supply probably is the problem.

Comment: I am using a 5.1v 10watt 2.1 amp USB power supply, A 4 LED strip that draws 62 ma, amplifier draws 360 ma, the only thing so far that eliminates the problem is using 2 different power supplies. Removing one speaker does not resolve problem, removing both speakers does.

Comment: IMG_2513.JPG  schematic

Answer (score 1):

As people have said in the comments, it sounds like your voltage is sagging. That's different from electrical noise.

Things to try:

- Buy a beefier 5v supply
- Use separate supplies for the 2 devices (the grounds can be connected).
- Look for poor connections that have excess resistance.

Comment: How do I add a jpg to a post?

Comment: click the edit button, then use the button that looks like a picture